# name of the shopping cart table in zencart database

Tags: zen-cart

I would like to know the name of the table in which the product name and other sopping cart details like quantity etc are saved in zen cart before the payment is completed.

Once I add an item to my cart and logged out and again logged in and add another item then I can see both if these item in my cart. So I think the data is saves in database. I would like to know whats its table name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's zen_**customers_basket**. Shopping cart data are in session untill you login, once you login all shopping cart data copy to zen_customers_basket table. If you logout without placing an order then those product automatically add on your shopping cart when you login back.